# How to program Raspberry Pi tiny RP 2040

Tags: raspberry-pi

I am trying to program my tiny RP 2040 board for the first time. I have generated the uf2 file and try to connect the board via USB to have it as a mounted USB drive. However, after holding the boot button and connecting it to USB Port of my computer (Windows 10), no USB mass drive appears. What can be the solution?
Here are some details:

- I have connected the board through a tested working cable
- I have connected the board to no supply voltage. I think it will be supplied through USB.
- I have not installed any drivers? Is it the case?

Comment: Take a look in device manager, if the driver had some problem it can be that Windows is not mounting the device.

Answer (score 0):

Easily the board was broken! I changed it and it worked fine this time!